# WPF color matrix

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview, matrix, grid

I have created a Class called matrix (Matrix [,] matrix;) and there I have the i and j attributes, which refer to the corresponding row and column.

Let's say, for example, that the [1,6] cell contains the number 6 (the content does not really matter as it is an example), or I want to represent it with a red color since 6 is greater than 5.

What I was wondering is what is the best and easiest way to represent this matrix in a Grid (Grid, Datagrid, ...) and for example change the [1,6] element of this grid to the red color, displaying it as the original matrix. This is an example I had but it dows not work, in fact it does not even create a Grid:

```
System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
...loop for dt...
dt.Columns.Add();
dt.Rows.Add();
datagrid1.DataSource = dt;
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is just one of many possible solutions:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding SomeMatrix}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid IsItemsHost="True" Columns="{Binding SomeMatrix.Columns}" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label Content="{Binding}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

U can then change the appearance of individual cells by modyfying the item template. The only prerequisite is that your `Matrix` class should implement `IEnumerable` interface and should yield items in a column-by-column, row-by-row order.